# Operation aborted Exception in WIN10 when using SHDocVw Navigate2 for navigatng ie

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, iwebbrowser2, shdocvw

I have a C# project that open urls in an IE Browser using **Interop.SHDocVw**.

The code is using a single instance of a InternetExplorerClass object and navigates to different urls. These urls are all in the **Intranet** zone.

The code works fine on **WIN7** but on **WIN10** there is a problem.
The IE browser opens the url correctly in the first time but when I try to use it in the second time using the navigate or navigate2 methods I get the following error:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004004): Operation aborted (Exception from  HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
   at  SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass.Navigate(String URL, Object& Flags, Object& TargetFrameName, Object& PostData, Object& Headers)**

I tried to run the host application "as administrator" and then it worked fine.
Also when I navigate manually in the IE window to a url in **internet** zone there is no problem, but when navigating manually to a different **intranet** url and trying to run the code in the second time, the error is being thrown again.

**The code**:

public static void IEOpenOnURL(string url) 
        { 
            object o = null; 
            bool newBrowser =false;

```
        //check if window is already opened 
        if(webBrowser==null)
        {
            newBrowser = true;
        }
        else
        {               
            try 
            {
                //Cannot navigate in browser with an open modal dialog
                if(webBrowser.Busy)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("הדפדפן תפוס - סגור את החלונות הקופצים מתוך הדפדפן הפתוח");
                    return;
                }
            }
            //an error is thrown when the browser was closed by user
            catch(Exception)
            {
                newBrowser = true;
            }
        } 

        if(newBrowser)
        { 
            //create new instance of the browser
            InternetExplorer explorer = new InternetExplorerClass(); 
            webBrowser = (IWebBrowser2)explorer;  
        } 


        webBrowser.Visible = true; 
        //webBrowser.Navigate(url, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
        webBrowser.Navigate2(url, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);

        //Set focus 
        SetForegroundWindow((IntPtr)webBrowser.HWND);
        //If browser is minimized - show it
        ShowWindow((IntPtr)webBrowser.HWND,9);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Yosi, we a re experiencing the same issue. Did you ever find a way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to say I know the exact answer offhand. But I would say you normally are supposed to initialize Internet Explorer via the interface instead of the class. I have run into errors when I have tried to initialize the class directly.

Try this :

```
  SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
  IE.Visible = true;
```